# How to fix this issue

Tags: software-installation

I'm a very new user to Ubuntu. Recently I was trying to upload my PHP project on my Ubuntu server, but every time I try to complete it shows error messages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not have write permission to the /var/ folder. With Linux, you should install your software as "sudo".

If installation is a GUI app, the software should be execute with `pkexec`.

Example

```
pkexec installMyPHP
```